# Proving that ($Z/pZ$)*,*p) is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let p be a prime number and let ($Z/pZ$)*={1,2,...,p-1}. For a,b$\in$($Z/pZ$)*, define a$\cdot$$_p$b as the remainder of ab in the division by p. Show that (($Z/pZ$)*,a$\cdot$$_p$b) is a group.

You need to prove associativity, and the existence of inverses and the existence of an identity.

Associativity can be proven directly, and
I know that 1 is the identity element.

How do I prove the existence of an inverse? I believe it has to do with the gcd of each element and p being one.

Comment: You can't *seriously* expect the ugly " a*pb " be understood as, say $\;a*_pb\;$, or even better: $\;a\cdot_p b\;$  . You could simply write $\;a*b\;$ and drop the subindex p for the sake of simplicity and clearity...or better: learn how to use MathJaX in this site.

Comment: im reading the tutorial, im trying to see how to express the second option you presented in MathJax

Comment: It does have to do with the gcd being $1$. For given $a$, write $1$ as a linear combination and discover the inverse!

Comment: Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity